# Dragonfly tag homonymy

Tags: discussion, tags

There are around 35 questions tagged [dragonfly](/questions/tagged/dragonfly).
Half of them are about [the Ruby gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/dragonfly) (or maybe RoR, not sure) and other half is about [the built-in debugger of the Opera browser](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/).

Don't know if they both should get a dash ([dragonfly-gem](/questions/tagged/dragonfly-gem) and [opera-dragonfly](/questions/tagged/opera-dragonfly)), or only one of them, or if the quantity is (by far) not yet a problem.

Comment: Now is the time to fix these, while the quantity is still low. 35 posts can get tag edits in a few minutes, if it grows to 350 or 3500 it's a major project.

Comment: I'm willing to go through 10 or so if a 1.5k user would kindly create the tags.  [Here's a question on which to create dragonfly-gem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7634869/325514) and [here's a question on which to create opera-dragonfly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374918/userscript-empty-error-console-in-opera).

Comment: I see somebody has added [tag:dragonfly-gem], and i added [tag:opera-dragonfly] today, added tag wiki and retagged related questions.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer - if your offer is still valid, can you make Ruby community a service, please ? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Done**, all ruby questions are now in [dragonfly-gem](/questions/tagged/dragonfly-gem) and all browser debugger questions are in [opera-dragonfly](/questions/tagged/opera-dragonfly).

Would be nice if somebody with 2500 reputation suggested [dragonfly](/questions/tagged/dragonfly) as synonym for browser tag - but that's only my personal and biased opinion ;)